# How to set default tasks.json in VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, visual-studio-code

Everytime i write a c++ code in VS Code, it forces me to configure build task. I found a string that works on YouTube and I paste it everytime. Is there a way to set default settings for tasks.json file for every c++ file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a default tasks.json file for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141850/how-can-i-set-a-default-tasks-json-file-for-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

Install [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) Extension. You can build and run using `Ctrl+Alt+N` or right click and select `Run Code` when the file is open. If you want your own build command you can add entry to `settings.json` ( `Ctrl+,` and click `{}` on top right corner to open).

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "g++ $fullFileName && ./a.out"
}
```

Replace the g++ command with your own command.